# Devise. Registration and Login at the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm trying to integrate Devise into my application. I need implement login form at top of the page (I've implemented this form into layout page) and I've implemented registration which contains registration form. 
But it shows validation errors for both form when I tried submit incorrect registration data.

Comment: can you show relevant views/controllers code?

Comment: [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17001874/1297435)  about this case.

Answer (score 6):

Without more information, it's hard to guess what the problem is.  I've found the Wiki pages to be really helpful (and increasingly so), though you may have already looked them over:

> [Devise Wiki Pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages)

Two pages that might be relevant to your needs:

> [Display a custom sign_in form anywhere in your app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app)
>
> [Create custom layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)

Hope this helps!

-- ff

Comment: I found problem it wasn't depend on the Devise. I change object name for each form and it works correctly.

Comment: @VitalyAksionchyk can you describe what you did in more detail?

Comment: For me, the change from `simple_form_for("User", ...` to `simple_form_for("user", ...` helped

Answer (score 3):

The problem of seeing the validation errors for both forms stems from the 2 things.  First, devise forms use a generic 'resource' helper. This creates a User object, and that same user objet gets used for both the sign up and the sign in form.  Second, devise errors are typically displayed using the 'devise_error_messages!' helper which uses that same shared resource.

To have sign in and sign up on the same page you need to create different user objects for each form, and a new way of displaying the error messages.

First off, you'll need to create your own registration controller (in app/controllers/users/)

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include DevisePermittedParameters

  protected

  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    super
    # Create an instance var to use just for the sign up form
    @sign_up_user = self.resource
  end
end
```

And update your routes file accordingly

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Next you'll need your own error messages and resource helpers.  Create a new helper like devise_single_page_helper.rb and add the following:

```
module DeviseSinglePageHelper
  def devise_error_messages_for_same_page(given_resource)
    return "" if given_resource.errors.empty?

    messages = given_resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      count: given_resource.errors.count,
                      resource: given_resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
    <ul>#{messages}</ul>
  </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

  def sign_up_user
    @sign_up_user ||= User.new(username: 'su')
  end

  def sign_in_user
    @sign_in_user ||= User.new(username: 'si')
  end
end
```

Finally, in your views, update your forms like so:

```
  -# The sign up form
  = simple_form_for(sign_up_user, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    -#...
    = devise_error_messages_for_same_page(sign_up_user)


  -# The sign in form
  = simple_form_for(sign_in_user, url: sessions_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    #...
    = devise_error_messages_for_same_page(sign_in_user)
```

All of this together gives you 2 different objects - 1 for sign up and 1 for sign in.  This will prevent the error messages from one showing in the other.  Please note that recommend putting both forms on your sign in page (and perhaps having the default sign up page redirect to the sign in page) because by default a failed sign in attempt will redirect to the sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two forms on the page — one for signing up and one for registering. If you want a single form and multiple potential actions you are going to need a couple buttons that get handled client side and change the form's action & method to the appropriate route depending you want to create a user or a session.

If you think you did this already, the problem almost certainly lies in your code. If you were to share it with us we could perhaps point out something you may have missed.