# Rails Devise Custom Registration and Login at the same page issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Ruby app, I am using the 'devise' gem for authentication but I want to customize the views, generate the devise views after customizing each of them and saving them in the devise folder as a partial, because I want to render them in another views.

So my issues are, the `new/sessions` is working, but when I try to sign up, it seems there's an issue with the form posting. See [login form](http://fast-plateau-1053.herokuapp.com/login) here.

I read a lot  about how to customize the layout in the devise documentation, but I am a little confused on how to implement to make the form render work outside the devise views folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, your question is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097386/devise-registration-and-login-at-the-same-page), but I'll explain a little bit and I'm try to do it.

1. Customize registration devise. ([customize devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise))
2. Make a custom login form beside on registration form. ([wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app))

---

Step by step :

1. **Create controller for customize registration and inherit from default registration devise**

   ```
   # customize registration controller
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     layout 'login'
     skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
     before_filter :resource_name

     def resource_name
       :user
     end

     def new  
       @user = User.new
     end

     def create
       @user = User.new(params[:user])
       # another stuff here
     end
   end
   ```
2. **Create controller for customize session and inherit from default session devise**

   ```
   # customize session controller
   class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
     def create
       super
     end
   end
   ```
3. **Create registration views** `app/registrations/new.html.erb`

   **Put login and registration form into** `app/registrations/new.html.erb`. **(beside on registration form looks like your project)**

   ```
   <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%# another stuff here %>  
   <% end %>

   <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%# another stuff here %>
   <% end %>
   ```
4. **Override devise mapping method in application helper**

   ```
   module ApplicationHelper
     def resource_name
       :user
     end

     def resource
       @resource ||= User.new
     end

     def devise_mapping
       @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
     end
   end
   ```
5. **Route for customize registration devise and session**

   ```
   devise_scope :user do
     # using login path for registration
     get '/login' => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
     post '/signup' => 'registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
     post '/signin' => 'sessions#create', :as => :user_session
   end
   ```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks , i'm going try to implement it , the way you said , see how it gonna be

Comment: This works really well, atm I sometime get directed to signup (e.g. if I try to sign up with bad username, but that's probably 'my fault"...)

Comment: @AndyHayden it's a security vulnerability if you redirect when a bad username is guessed. You leak which usernames you *do* have. Please don't do this!

Comment: @quantumpotato Very true, I think that was a mistype I meant bad username & password combo... I'm not actually using devise anymore but if it was redirecting to sign up rather than sign in that's not that great. :s

Comment: In case of incorrect Data it will not show errors the customized/your made pages.

Comment: @quantumpotato Aren't usernames/ emails already leaked in a similar process if you try to sign up with an existing username? I.e. sign up with random usernames and see if the name is taken?