# ruby on rails, devise custom signup and login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to get my devise working for my rails project. I am customizing the views. I got it to accept and authenticate a name field and an email password with this code:

In my config and initializer devise file

```
config.authentication_keys = [:name, :email]
```

and in my new session view

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <% if resource.errors.has_key?(:name) %>
     <em><%= resource.errors[:name] %></em>
   <% end %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name, autocomplete: "off" %>
 </div>
```

If I remove the `authentication_key` for the name it never saves the name so I added the key to the `authentication_keys` and it works

however, for login I don't want to it to authenticate the email and just work by the name and password

and i am having problems in doing that

I checked the `sign_up` and it works and creates a new user with all the data.

let me know if you got any ideas, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000497/rails-devise-custom-registration-and-login-at-the-same-page-issues Something like this?

Comment: maybe, it looks a bit out of my playing field. i was wondering if there was a way without creating a custom controller, i will play with it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want just use name for login then change authentication keys  without email

```
  config.authentication_keys = [:name]
```

### additional code

if you want to include email when user sign_up

open your application controller and add below code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email])
  end
end
```

Comment: if i take the :email away I have the problem of passing the :email in the sign_up which i am trying to save. for some reason it doesn't read it, I checked the POST action and it does get passed but for some reason devise doesnt check it out and says its always blank. and i looked through stackoverflow and found the answer of putting into the authentication_keys. But for the login i need it to be different.

Comment: I add answer for your problem

Comment: Yes you did! Thank you so much Master! :)